# Error on weighted histogram in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram, weighted

I want to calculate the error on a bin height by taking the square root of the sum of the weights squared (sumw2) in that bin (poission error). Is there any way to get the sum of weights (sumw) and/or sumw2 when histogramming data with either matplotlib or numpy (or any other library for that matter)?

Let's say I have some data in a numpy array `x` and some weights `w` in another numpy array, to get the histogram I would either so

```
n, bins, patches = pyplot.hist(x,weights=w)
```

or

```
n, bins = numpy.histogram(x,weights=w)
```

In both cases I have no clue which entries of `w` belong to which bin right?

Edit: Currently I'm using [YODA](https://yoda.hepforge.org/) to do this. The disadvantage from my point of view is that YODA histograms can only be filled with one data point at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to numpy [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html), weights

> An array of weights, of the same shape as a. Each value in a only
>   contributes its associated weight towards the bin count (instead of
>   1). If density is True, the weights are normalized, so that the
>   integral of the density over the range remains 1.

That means that each value in `w` should be associated with a value in `x`. If you'd like to weight bins and plot them, you can first find bins' values, multiply them by weights and finally plot them using `bar`.

```
val, pos = np.histogram(np.arange(1000))
w_val = val * w
plt.bar(pos[1:], w_val)
```

---

Update from the comment:

Ahh, sorry, it seems that I didn't understand the initial question. Actually, you can use `pos` to find cells related to each bin and calculate your weight function using these information.

```
for left, right in zip(pos, pos[1:): 
    ix = np.where((x >= left) & (x <= right))[0] 
    sumw2 = np.sum(w[ix] ** 2)
```

Comment: This does not work if the number of bins is not the number of entries in a, since `len(val)==nbins` and `len(w)==len(a)` or am I missing something?

Comment: @Lxndr could you please explain what is `a`?

Comment: Oh sorry `a` (from the documentation) is `x` from my example above if I understand the documentation correctly.

Comment: Ok, if `len(x) == len(w)` then in `numpy.histogram(x,weights=w)` `x[i]` is associated with `w[i]`

Comment: But then there is still no way to get sumw2 for each bin. By handing the weights to `numpy.histogram()` one would just change the height of the bins, i.e. the `val` array. The error of the bins stays inaccessible..

Comment: Ahh, sorry, it seems that I didn't understand the initial question. Actually, you can yes `pos` to find cell related to each bean and calculate your weights.  

   for left, right in zip(pos, pos[1:):
       ix = np.where((x >= left) & (x <= right))[0]
       sumw2 = np.sum(w[ix] ** 2)

Comment: This is it! Thanks a lot. Can we somehow make this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3):

Consider an array `x` with weights `w`. The histogram of the data in `x` weighted by `w` with `bins` is given by:

```
n, bins = np.histogram(x, bins=bins, weights=w)
```

And the associated errors to n can be computed as:

```
n_err = np.sqrt(np.histogram(x, bins=bins, weights=w**2)[0])
```

Note that if the data is not weighted (i.e. `(w == 1).all()`) then the error reduces to the "standard" `np.sqrt(n)`